# Datetime format in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to show a datetime column in the following fromat `04/11/2016 01:38:03 PM`, but it is showing in the format `4/11/2016 1:38:03 PM`.

Is there any specific function or syntax to get that desired format?

Comment: This is presentation matter and should be handled in application layer. Of course you could use `CONVERT/FORMAT` if you reallly have to

Comment: yes, i can. But did not find any specific syntax for that.

Comment: Datetime fields have no inherent format. If you want to change the presentation, you have to convert it to `(n)varchar` with the desired format.

Comment: I have used select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(), 103)  +  RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),GETDATE(),100),8) but it showing the value "11/04/2016  3:15PM"

Comment: For the date part use that one: CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(), 101)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose function FORMAT should help you:

```
select 
   FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt');
```

More details about format you can found in official documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634398.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you output in exact same format(04/11/2016 01:38:03 PM) :

```
select FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt');
```

See the output:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf3YB.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this..

```
select FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt');
```